# Applying function using multiple columns as argument , function returns a data.frame

Tags: r, function, apply

I am trying to apply a function that uses multiple columns of a dataframe as arguments, with the function returning a dataframe for each row. I can use a for loop here, but Wanted to check if there is any other way of doing this

A simple example is being provided here. my original problem is slightly more complicated.

```
DF1<-data.frame(start=seq(from=1, to=5, by=1),end=seq(from=10, to=14, by=1))

rep_fun <- function(x,y)
{
  data.frame( A=seq(x, y)) #produces a sequence between x and y
}

DF2<-data.frame()
for (i in 1:nrow(DF1)){
  temp<-data.frame(rep_fun(DF1$start[i],DF1$end[i]))
 DF2<-rbind(temp,DF2) # this contains a dataframe that has a sequence between 'start' and 'end' for  each row in DF1 

}
```

The desired result which I am able to obtain through a for-loop is shown below. Not all rows are being shown here. Rows 1 to 10, shows the sequence corresponding to row 5 in DF1

```
> DF2
    A
1   5
2   6
3   7
4   8
5   9
6  10
7  11
8  12
9  13
10 14
11  4
12  5
```

Comment: I trust this is a case of the xy problem. But here is a possible approach: `as.vector(apply(DF1, 1,  function(x) x[1] : x[2]))`

Comment: As I had mentioned, my original problem is more complicated. The rep_fun equivalent in my original problem will return a multi row and multi column data frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) lapply** Split `DF1` by `nrow(DF1):1` so that it comes out in reverse order and then `lapply` over that list and `rbind` its components together.  No packages are used.

```
DF3 <- do.call("rbind", lapply(split(DF1, nrow(DF1):1), with, rep_fun(start, end)))
rownames(DF3) <- NULL

identical(DF2, DF3)
## [1] TRUE
```

**2) Map** or this alternative:

```
fun <- function(x) with(x, rep_fun(start, end))
DF4 <- do.call("rbind", Map(fun, split(DF1, nrow(DF1):1), USE.NAMES = FALSE))

identical(DF4, DF2)
## [1] TRUE
```

**3) Map/rev**  Like (2) this uses `Map` but this time using `rep_fun` directly.  Also, it uses `rev` to order the output after the computation rather than `split` to order the input before the computation.

```
DF5 <- do.call("rbind", with(DF1, rev(Map(rep_fun, start, end))))

identical(DF5, DF2)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: The reversing thing wasnt a requirement to be honest, but great to find out that is possible! Option 3 is the one I am going with. Its about 3 times faster than the For loop option in my original problem!